How to change Data_directory parameters for PostgreSQL on Windows
I've changed the parameters in postgresql.conf as
data_directory = 'E:\PostgreSQL\12\data'

But for some reason, it try to start using  C:/Windows/system32/E:PostgreSQL/data

Why it add C:/Windows/system32/? Does not make sence and I've tried it in my virtual box lab and in a production server. Got the same issue in both envoriments

I am not a Windows person, but try /e/PostgreSQL/12/data.

Not working with /e/PostgreSQL/12/data

In the config file, \ is used as an escape character, to either give or take away special meanings to the character following it.  You either need to escape it itself, by doubling them to \\, or you could use the forward slash instead of the backslash as the path delimiter.  Based on the error message, it looks like \P gets interpreted as P itself, while \12 get interpreted as a control character.
Since the \ following 'E:' has gone missing, this is interpreted as a relative path, not an absolute one.
